# Modifying .htaccess file to set include path to ZendFramework

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, include

I'm trying to include ZendFramework on a web site with no luck. Lately I gave a try at modifying the .htaccess file like this:

```
php_value include_path ":/home/u230474/Zend"
```

I also tried

```
php_value include_path ".:/home/u230474/Zend"
```

But on each case what happened was that I no longer could view any of the pages in the web site.

I did these modifications since I'm trying to make the system understand the following code:

```
<?php 
$libreria='/Zend/ZendFramework/library';
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.$libreria);
require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

I've been trying things many days long now, and although I've talked to my provided we seem to have problems understanding the requirements.

I did a test to check the installation of ZendFramework with a script called InstallationChecker.php which is supposed to indicate the success in installing Zend Framework, and actually the script throws an error like this:

```
Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php using 'use_include_path' = true. Make sure you include Zend Framework in your include_path which currently contains: .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php
```

Which is why I tried modifying .htaccess

Does anyone know if I'm doing things wrong (obviously yes)? What is the right way to modify the htaccess file so that `/usr/lib/php and /usr/local/lib/php are included as well?

Also I've read that when you include a htaccess you must include also a .htaccess file to every subdirectory that makes an include. Most of my php scripts are directly in the public folder, but still I have many of them on subdirectories as well. How am I supposed to proceed?

I made some changes following Mike's advise and included the whole custom path like this:

```
$libreria='Zend/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Loader';
```

then I looked at php.info and it still doesn't show any changes to include_path. Additionally, I noticed that the error in the test I'm running to check if ZendFramework is installed is telling me there's a class Loader.php in the Zend folder, which is actually there, but still nothing gets loaded.

Ok so I did a couple of test to see what's going wrong, since the Zend Framework seems to load ok. First I added this code to the file 'libreria.php' which sets the include path (apparently alright, since the library is loaded). I did this:

```
$libreria='/home/u230474/public_classes/Zend/ZendFramework/library';
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.$libreria);
require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
$libload = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
if(!$libload) echo "Librer&iacute;a Zend Framework cargada"; else echo "Error al cargar la librer&iacute;a";
```

And as a result, it outputs: "Error al cargar la librería".

I also set up a tiny test to see if there's something wrong with the case sensitivity. On some of the pages that are having trouble, I put this code inmediately after including the header and the library:

```
//codigo para probar equidad de nombre de archivo---------->
$filename = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
$request = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
if($filename != $request)
  die('Case of filename and request do not match!');
```

And it does not die, so it's ok. (If I get it right the result would be different if there was a slight difference in my file names, as are seen on the browser address, and as are seen by the server, but maybe I'm wrong).

Then, there's something going on with the way I call the Autoloader.php class, but I don't see a different way of calling it than the static method on Zend's introduction to Autoloader documentation, where it says 'Autoloader, basic usage'

Comment: Check your error_reporting levels and/or your PHP error log. If the autoloader is returning false, something is wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess is probably not the place to make this change, as it will be more difficult to append the new path you want to include to the existing.  What you did was overwrite all the include paths with just the one you specified in .htaccess.  This blowd things up.

If you look at the 2nd line of the PHP code you included, it shows you how to append to the include path (by getting the current path and appending a new path to it.) Just do similar for the path you want to include.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I do. I have the php code in a file called libreria.php which I require_once on the scripts I need it, but then I wonder why the script InstallationChecker.php throws me the error above, and does not show every piece of ZendFramework as tested. I talked to my provider and they say it might be a problem of capitalization compatibility (I developed in windows) but all my files are invoked exactly with camel Case and mysql tables are in lowercase originally, so I can't find what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks but that's what I do. I've got that php code in a file called libreria.php which I require on every script that I need to. I have tried with lots of paths, including relative like ../, and even the root / but none work. My provider says it's probably a capitalization issue (I develop on Windows) but I invoke every script exactly the way it was written in camelCase and mysql tables are in lowercase originally, so I don't see the problem. Also, info.php gives me this as include_path: `.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php`so should I edit the .htaccess with these?

Comment: I did change the htaccess despite your advice, including the path to /usr/lib/php, and the rest, and as you predicted, I merely broke the whole site. But as I said, I've tried in every possible way to set the include path (without changing php.ini, which I can't) and haven't been able to solve it. Should I simply include the class Autoloader.php on every script. It definitely wouldn't be elegant.

Comment: Also, if I look at the include_path on my own Wamp Server I see it's C:\php\pear; I really don't know much about pear and also cannot change this value on my remote, but there's another question. I see that php on the remote is handled as a FastCGI API, so might that be a problem with installing the ZendFramework

Comment: Last editing: what I did was to place the code snippet to set_include_path right on the script installation_checker, and now my test for Zend Framework installation passes, I followed advises I've read here on this site to place the Zend Framework on a sister folder to the public folder. I'll look if I can just include the file called libreria.php so that I figure out why my code isn't working. Guess I'll keep posting

Comment: Guess my provider is right and there's a capitalization problem. Although the test for ZendFramework installation passes my script seems to get nowhere. However, when I test it locally it does work, and even the mail gets sent when I provide PHPMailer with the right credentials of the mail server.